# How to use multiple regex groups in pyspark?

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regex-group

I want to insert a symbol between two regex groups.

My code is as follows:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('ab',)], ['str'])
df = df.select(
  concat(
    regexp_extract('str', r'(\w)(\w)', 1),  # extract the first group
    lit(' '),                               # add symbol
    regexp_extract('str', r'(\w)(\w)', 2)   # add the second group
  ).alias('d')).collect()
print(df)
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` with capture groups:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select(F.regexp_replace('str', r'(\w)(\w)', '$1 $2').alias('d')).show()
+---+
|  d|
+---+
|a b|
+---+
```

Comment: thanks. I tried `regexp_replace('str', r'(\w)(\w)', '\1 \2')` with standard `re` group markers and it didn't work. Is use of `$` in pyspark documented somewhere ?